# Thermal Image Processing Filters/Method to improve quality

Tags: python, image-processing

Currently, I am working with the MLX90640 thermal camera sensor and need to find out how to improve the quality of the image. Could someone recommend to me what filters/ processing methods are for my problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uD75.png)

Comment: There's nothing like a magical image improvement. You have to be more specific what kind of improvement you are trying to archive. Also you show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have just processed the raw data and visualized it. I am finding a way that could improve the image quality with low computational effort:
+ make the human/hot object easier to identify
+ reduce the noise in the image (especially in the corners)

Answer (score 0):

You can interpolate the image at higher resolution with the different algorithms, using opencv for example, to make it more "beauty for humans".

https://chadrick-kwag.net/cv2-resize-interpolation-methods/

Then, using a normal camera, get the edges of the camera image and overlay them with the MLX90640. When superimposing images you have to take into account the deformation of the lenses, it does not always look good at all distances. It is something similar to what the Flir cameras do.

With opencv, you can smooth the generated images by applying opencv image filters to remove some noise.
And perhaps most interestingly, convert your grayscale image to a heatmap.

Also, as you have an array with all the data, you can always show ranges of temperatures defined by you, some examples:

- Show only pixels between 30 to 37 degrees and "turn off" by setting
  all other pixels to zero.
- Calculate the values ​​close to a fixed temperature and display them
  by turning off the other pixels, something like taking the maximum
  temperature of the matrix and displaying only the pixels that have a
  range of 5 or 3 degrees of difference.